# Android: XML parsing: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: Only one root element allowed

Tags: android, xml-parsing, domexception

I am trying to parse an xml file. But i get this error:
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: Only one root element allowed
at the line:

```
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(getAssets().open("myfile.xml"));
```

Please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: XML can only have one root element:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have only one root, it means you must have only once a tag that surround every all tags. For example you can surround all your tags by `<root></root>`

Also, try to validate your xml file with an xml validator in order to see if your xml is malformed.